# Signed url with IE11 doesn't work

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, internet-explorer-11

I.e. version 11.0.9431.0

I am not able to upload file to google cloud storage from IE11, I am able to upload same file with same code from firefox, It is showing me error with CORS not enabled, but I have enabled CORS on bucket of google cloud storage

CORS that I've set is:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["accept-encoding", "cache-control", "content-length", "content-type",     "expect", "if-modified-since", "origin", "range", "referer", "x-goog-acl", "x-goog-api-version"],
    "method": ["GET","PUT","HEAD","OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 900
  }
]

Error on console that I get on IE11 is:

SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://storage.googleapis.com/buckethha/file.jpg?GoogleAccessId=748853424295-p1es6br4fmi7ub4gd3junmu6n4fbcr0j@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1410349523&Signature=ImoOVE0XUBPOfCzMGrNXG0W1P1xJE80Jyee5gD%2FMcCp0uTxVf9GdMTayNESFw4qslrcDMMjU1otI4O4s15pMx9g136uEWnVkDrLc3hN6LGcnFpd1VuV9cjB%2BewnuHs3AqVJYH9PCKXNCkl%2FR%2Bwwm4rrKOjz3KApAAZblCzEeoFE%3D required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).File: UploadSignedUrlPut.php
SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for https://storage.googleapis.com/buckethha/file.jpg?GoogleAccessId=748853424295-p1es6br4fmi7ub4gd3junmu6n4fbcr0j@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1410349523&Signature=ImoOVE0XUBPOfCzMGrNXG0W1P1xJE80Jyee5gD%2FMcCp0uTxVf9GdMTayNESFw4qslrcDMMjU1otI4O4s15pMx9g136uEWnVkDrLc3hN6LGcnFpd1VuV9cjB%2BewnuHs3AqVJYH9PCKXNCkl%2FR%2Bwwm4rrKOjz3KApAAZblCzEeoFE%3D required CORS preflight.File: UploadSignedUrlPut.php
```

My HTML-php code is -> http://pastebin.com/qCkT1mr8

Note: What should I add in code or request to solve this problem?
IE 9,10 and 11 are officially supported browser of my application, so I have to fix this in some way

Comment: I think this might be due to the fact that you are simply using the `XMLHttpRequest` object in your JS code – I’d suggest you use a library/framework like f.e. jQuery that takes care of the cross-browser issues for you …

Comment: But IE10 and 11 Does support xmlhttprequest 
http://caniuse.com/#search=xmlhttprequest

Comment: @CBroe And it also show me XMLHTTPRequest warning message, that would have happened only if My request was sent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking closely I came to know that the Warning that are shown in I.E. isn't pointing me to the correct direction, Actual issue was that while uploading file with PUT firefox was sending the content-type with the request, and that is why my signature was matching with Google, and IE doesn't send it explicitly, so adding it had solved my problem

```
i.e. 
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
```